# Sharing a Binding Source Between Two Controls Not Working

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm creating a form that will act as a master-detail editor. I have 2 controls on this form. One is basically a list of mater items and the other control is the details of the item. I'm trying to use a the same BindingSource object in both controls so that when a change is made on the master control, the detail control will get updated.

In my form I have:

```
EmployerCollection employerCollection = new EmployerCollection();
employerCollection.GetMulti(null, 0, new SortExpression(EmployerFields.Name | SortOperator.Ascending));
bsEmployers.DataSource = employerCollection;

masterControl.Init(bsEmployers);
detailControl.Init(bsEmpoyers);
```

In my masterControl I have:

```
public void Init(BindingSource bs)
{
    bsEmployers = bs;
}
```

However for the life of me I can't get my master control to display the data in the binding source when I pass it in this way.

I can get binding to work only if I remove the bsEmployers = bs line and move the other logic as follows:

```
public void Init(BindingSource bs)
    {
        EmployerCollection employerCollection = new EmployerCollection();
        employerCollection.GetMulti(null, 0, new SortExpression(EmployerFields.Name |             SortOperator.Ascending));
        bsEmployers.DataSource = employerCollection;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can't pass the BindingSource object in to share it? I tried calling RefreshBindings in my control, but it did not seem to have any effect.

Thanks.

Comment: when you assign  bsEmployers = bs; you overwrite the reference of your binding source, but all your controls are still bound to old bsEmployers. Try removing your binding source from form designer and create it programmatically and assign it to all child controls that are using it. Also you can try to call bsEmployers.DataSource = bs.DataSource;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the BindingSource was intended to be used that way. I would recommend passing the EmployerCollection value to the Init method and have each control create its own BindingSource using the EmployerCollection.